# Parsec's setState does not reset consume status

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to understand, how Parsec resets its state, and what is part of that state. I am surprise about the behavior of the following code:

```
parseAbReset :: Parser Char                                                                    
parseAbReset = do                                                                              
    st <- getParserState                                                                  
    char 'A'                                                                              
    ret <- char 'b' <|> (setParserState st >> fail mempty)                                
    return ret                                                                            


parseFinal :: Parser Char                                                                     
parseFinal = parseAbReset <|> (char 'A' >> char 't')
```

I would expect `parseFinal` to successfully parse "At". Here is my reasoning (the | denotes the current state on the input):
the `<|>` tries `parseAbReset`, that parses until "A|t", then it fails on `char 'b'` without consuming input, and so resets the state back to "|At", parseAbReset fails (and in my opinion it should fail without consuming input, since it is reset to a state before it has consumed input). That allows the alternative `(char 'A' >> char 't')` to consume "At" and we end in "At|".

In other examples, I have tested that setParserState resets the position in the stream successfully, but it seems the state whether it has consumed something or not is not reset.

Any ideas, how I can also reset whether it has consumed or not?

Answer (score 1):

The stream position is not part of the parser state, so resetting the parser state can't influence what inputs have been consumed. The one use of {get,set}ParserState in Parsec itself is in [`lookahead`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-1.0.1.8/docs/src/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#lookAhead). As you can see, it does some work to preserve the input stream in addition to preserving parser state. It helpfully remarks that if it consumes input in cases where you wish it wouldn't, you should use `try`. This makes sense: `try` is the typical Parsec tool for recovering from a partial failed parse.

And indeed what you're trying to do is very simple with `try`:

```
parseAbReset :: Parser Char
parseAbReset = try $ char 'A' *> char 'b'
```

Comment: There is a difference (though not in the exact example): if ``char 'b'`` is a more complicated parser that can fail with consuming input, then my code above would not reset, while try always resets. That is the reason I cannot use try, and want to mess with {get,set}ParserState.

Comment: To follow up on your suggestion to look at try and lookahead. Is there an explanation out there somewhere, what happens when you shuffle the cok cerr eok eerr internals around?